# regex to ignore everything between negative lookbehind and match

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I know that pretty much every regex question must have been asked and answered, but here I go:

I want a regex to match:

```
"alcohol abuse"
"etoh abuse"
"alcohol dependence"
"etoh dependence"
```

but not to match

```
"denies alcohol dependence"
"denies smoking and etoh dependence"
"denies [anything at all] and etoh abuse"
```

The negative lookbehind is obvious, but how to I NOT match the final two examples?

So far my regex looks like this:

```
re.compile("(?<!denies\s)(alcohol|etoh)\s*(abuse|dependence)")
```

I cannot include a greedy operator in the negative lookbehind as that operation only works with a fixed length string to be evaluated.

I would prefer to do this in one step as it feeds to a function that accepts one regex as a parameter.

Thanks for the tips

Comment: Are additional modules (i.e. `regex` which supports an infinite lookbehind) allowed?

Comment: Im working in a VM where that would not be installed, but I would totally install it if there is no solution in `re`. If possible in `re` that would be amazing

Comment: Yes, with PyPi regex module, you may use `(?<!denies.*?(?:alcohol|etoh)\s*)(?:abuse|dependence)`, but - depending on what you need exactly (extract or replace) - you may also have a kind of  a workaround with `re`.

Comment: Actually I simply and using the fact of the match in some conditional logic. No need to extract or replace. Thanks for regex tip though, i didnt know about that module. Sadly I have no control over the VM. Im not trustworthy enough to be able to install packages on my own. sigh

Comment: @WoodyPride As a workaround you can match reversed strings and using a negative lookahead with the pattern reversed as well: `r'(ecnedneped|esuba)\s*(hote|lohocla)(?!.*seined)'`.

Comment: @WoodyPride Or you could chain another `re.sub` before, replacing all the `"[anything at all]"` part and then perform the match with fixed width negative lookbehind: `re.sub(r"denies\s.*(alcohol|etoh)\s*(abuse|dependence)", r"denies \1 \2", string)`.

Comment: @WoodyPride Or to clarify a general question, do you have access to the strings to be matched as well? I mean could you perform any modifications such as reversal or additional substitution before the matching?

Comment: Maybe try a negative lookahead `^(?!.*?denies\s.*(?:alcohol|etoh)\s*(?:abuse|dependence)).+$` [test](https://regex101.com/r/P4yF7T/1/)

Comment: I do have access to the strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cannot install any modules, you could reformulate your expression and check for the emptyness of group 1:

```
import re
rx = re.compile("(denies)?.*?(alcohol|etoh)\s*(abuse|dependence)")

sentences = ["alcohol abuse", "etoh abuse", "alcohol dependence", "etoh dependence",
             "denies alcohol dependence", "denies smoking and etoh dependence", "denies [anything at all] and etoh abuse"]

def filterSentences(input):
    m = rx.search(input)
    if m and m.group(1) is None:
        print("Yup: " + sent)

for sent in sentences:
    filterSentences(sent)
```

This yields

```
Yup: alcohol abuse
Yup: etoh abuse
Yup: alcohol dependence
Yup: etoh dependence
```

If you have more than `denies` (i.e. `does not like...`), just change the first caption group.

Comment: This is great. I actually never knew about using the match groups like that. Thanks!

Comment: @WoodyPride: Glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize [match groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html) and employ the following general pattern:

`bad|(good)`

You do actually match the parts you don't want first, but only the "good" part is remembered in the last part of the alternation.

So your pattern would then be (note all the "grouping only" parentheses):

`denies.*?(?:(?:alcohol|etoh)\s*(?:abuse|dependence))|((?:alcohol|etoh)\s*(?:abuse|dependence))`

"group 1" in this [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/hP4ZWI/2/) holds only valid matches.